# Why not free the memory from calloc() here (YOLO)

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I'm confused that why not free the memory from`calloc()`, when reading the project [YOLO](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet) which is written in C. Does it not cause any memory leak?

The code is below, or [check here](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/src/utils.c#L61).

```
void shuffle(void *arr, size_t n, size_t size)
{
    size_t i;
    void *swp = calloc(1, size); // not free
    for(i = 0; i < n-1; ++i){
        size_t j = i + rand()/(RAND_MAX / (n-i)+1);
        memcpy(swp,          arr+(j*size), size);
        memcpy(arr+(j*size), arr+(i*size), size);
        memcpy(arr+(i*size), swp,          size);
    }
}
```

Could someone give me an answer?

Comment: Note: there's a pull request to fix that bug: https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/pull/22

Answer (score 2):

That is a memory leak; You should always free *alloc'd memory.

Comment: You're quite right that the function in question leaks memory, but be careful with blanket statements.  You should always free \*alloc'd memory *when you're done with it*.  That isn't always before returning from the function in which the allocation occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It causes memory leak every time `shuffle()` is called.

If size is zero, the return value depends on the particular library implementation (it may or may not be a null pointer), in that case, the returned pointer shall not be dereferenced.

Recommended:

```
void shuffle(void *arr, size_t n, size_t size)
{
    if (size == 0)return;
    size_t i;
    void *swp = calloc(1, size); // not free
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i){
        size_t j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);
        memcpy(swp, arr + (j*size), size);
        memcpy(arr + (j*size), arr + (i*size), size);
        memcpy(arr + (i*size), swp, size);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G9P6.png)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the code you recommend hasn't free `swp` ?